# If anyone has experience with the Nvidia Jetbot, do you know how to change the gstreamer pipeline to work with a webcam? I'm using a c170 Logitech

Tags: python, gstreamer, nvidia

This pipeline works with a gst-launch-1.0 using 4l2:

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video2" name=e ! 'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480' ! videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, format=(string)YUY2' ! xvimagesink

and this is the pipeline used by the original module:

'nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=%d, height=%d, format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! appsink' % (
                self.capture_width, self.capture_height, self.fps, self.width, self.height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original module begins with `nvarguscamerasrc`, and ends with `appsink`. `nvarguscamerasrc` reads to NVVM memory, so you need to convert it to cpu memory with `nvvidconv`.

For v4l it reads directly to cpu memory so you don't need `nvvidconv`, however you need to convert it to BGR using `videoconvert` so I believe this should work:

```
'v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480 ! videoconvert !  appsink'
```